# Angular 4 -Convert the Text field value to uppercase on the fly

Tags: angular

I have a text field in my html page

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="myText" #origin="ngModel"  [(ngModel)]="defaultText" required pattern="[A-Z]{3}"/>
```

when user enter some text in text field in lower case letters, then it should converted to uppercase immediately

how to achieve it angular 4

Comment: You could create a custom directive.

Comment: What's the final goal? Passing the text somewhere else? Just display it somewhere (use uppercase pipe?)

Comment: @Maxime yes I want to show it in the same screen in upper case and pass to query

Comment: easy way without custome directive <input type="text" class="form-control" name="myText"   [(ngModel)]="defaultText" required pattern="[A-Z]{3}" (ngModelChange)="t.value = t.value.toUpperCase()" #t/>

Comment: Try this, <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{myText | uppercase}}" (input)="myText = $event.currentTarget.value" required pattern="[A-Z]{3}"/>